# The easiest way to transform WF controls to have rounded corners, and better look

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, frameworks, rounded-corners

So I have a existing .net software using Windows Forms Control forms.
Most of used controls inherit form basic Windows Forms like: button, ComboBox or TextBox which don't have rounded corners property.
Beside that, they don't follow the dark theme (for example the ComboBox will still only have dark textbox, but arrow and square behind it still will be white)

Example here

[image: example here]

So what's your recommendation to easily adjust look of existing controls ?
I want to make them dark theme and round coroner.

I have already tried to override On Paint metod, but i didn't figure out how to override it for example for ComboBox control.

Comment: IMHO The easiest way is to buy 3th party controls that can do this

Comment: @GuidoG do you have some recommendations ? And after buying it, if there is easy way to inherit from them, so I don't need to change every form that uses particular control ?

Comment: Recommendations are difficult, I use devexpress and am happy with it. But since I did not used any other, I have no means of doing an objective comparison